# Find out what happened to my data in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm using mongodb in a project. I shut down mongodb and when I restarted mongodb all my databases and collections were gone. How do I figure out what happened?

Comment: Is the dbpath same as before the restart?

Comment: @4j41 I don't know. I haven't changed anything but I can't find what the dbpath defaults to.

Comment: The default dbpath is /data/db. If you are using a configuration file, you can check there.

Comment: I haven't changed it.

Comment: Please add the command you executed to shut and start MongoDB. It'll be helpful.

Comment: I think ctrl-C was used to stop mongod. mongod was the command to start it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the files, you can check the db path. You can do this by using

`grep dbPath /etc/mongod.conf`

(on default installations). This should return a line with the path to the files.

If the first command does not work, you can use the command

`ps aux | grep mongo`

and search for the mongod process. There should be something like this on the output:

```
/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

If there is a --dbpath argument on the process, you should look there for the files.

And in case your files are not in the dbpath fodler, the last resource I can think of is searching for the files on the whole file system:

`sudo find / -name 'mongo*'`

(you should find the `mongod.lock` file in the folders that were already used by Mongo).

If you happen to find your files in another folder that is not being used by Mongo, then you'll have to change the dbPath on config.

Comment: grep dbPath /etc/mongod.conf tells me there is no file or directory. ps aux | grep mongo Doesn't output any file names. I went to /data/db, in there was a 'mongod.lock'. I noticed that there is a database called 'test' (the one I was/am using). I also noticed test.0, test.1, test.2, test.3, test.4, test.ns. What are all these test.* files?

Comment: These many files is how Mongodb structures the files on disk. Are you able to connect to the mongo running on your machine? If it was running I'm almost sure the process would be visible by running ps aux. How did you restart Mongo?

Comment: I can connect but typing 'ps aux | grep mongo' gives me some data about mongod but not a list of files. I typed mongod in my terminal to restart.

Comment: ps aux will only give you the process name, with it's parameters. You can try to use the mongod command as "mongod --dbpath /data/db"  So it is sure to use this folder